# I tried to update a label in Xamarin.Forms, and it broke the entire app

Tags: events, xamarin.forms, label

I have a label on my app's main page that is supposed to update every fifteen seconds, but it only updates once and after that, a lot of things stop working. For example, if I try to open a new page after the label updates, the page's title is drawn in the same place as the back button (both of which are generated in the toolbar by Xamarin), and the page's content doesn't load at all. Also, I have a ListView on the page and if I try to select an item (which is supposed to open a new page) it only works the first time, after which point the ListView disappears, but the orange box that appears behind a selected item stays there.

How the label works at the moment is I have a timer in the App class that chooses a random piece of text from a list that I load in the app's OnStart() function (that part works properly) and then fires an event that is supposed to update the label.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Timers;
using System.Reflection;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

using Partylist.Views;
using Partylist.Models;

namespace Partylist
{
    public partial class App : Application, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // Variable to store the currently selected event.
        public static Event selectedEvent;
        // Variable to store the currently selected list.
        public static PartylistList selectedList;
        // Struct to store information about tips.
        public struct Tip
        {
            // A short version of the tip for the banner at the bottom of the screen.
            public string Summary { get; set; }
            // The full tip, which you can read by clicking the "More" button in the banner.
            public string Full { get; set; }
        }
        // Array of tips.
        public List<Tip> tips = new List<Tip>();
        // Current tip.
        public Tip CurrentTip { get; set; }
        // Timer that gets the tip to update.
        public Timer tipTimer = new Timer(15000);
        // Random number generator for choosing the tip.
        public Random rand = new Random();
        // Event that tells the tip banners on the pages to update.
        public static event EventHandler TipUpdate;

        // Constructor.
        public App()
        {
            // Do whatever initialization stuff this does.
            InitializeComponent();

            // Subscribes the timer's event handling function to its event.
            tipTimer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;

            // Open the first page: the list of events.
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new EventsPage()) {
                BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("FF4081")
            };
        }

        // Loads tips data.
        private void LoadTips()
        {
            // Variable for the assembly.
            var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(App)).Assembly;
            // Variable for the stream I use to read the text file.
            Stream tipsStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Partylist.Resources.tips.txt");
            // And a variable for the StreamReader.
            StreamReader tipsReader = new StreamReader(tipsStream);
            // Read the whole file into the list of tips.
            while (!tipsReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                // Read a line into a "sumamry" variable.
                string sum = tipsReader.ReadLine();
                // Read another line into a "full" variable.
                string full = tipsReader.ReadLine();
                // Add an item to the list of tips that uses "summary" as the summary 
                // and "full" as the full tip.
                tips.Add(new Tip()
                {
                    Summary = sum,
                    Full = full
                });
            }
            // Random index of the chosen tip.
            int index = rand.Next(tips.Count);
            // Set the current tip as the tip at that index.
            CurrentTip = tips.ElementAt(index);
            // Start timer (if it needs it).
            tipTimer.Start();
        }

        // Event handling function for when the timer goes off.
        private void OnTimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Random index of the chosen tip.
            int index = rand.Next(tips.Count);
            // Set the current tip as the tip at that index.
            CurrentTip = tips.ElementAt(index);
            // Fire the event to update the pages' tip banners.
            TipUpdate?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

        // Standard lifecycle events.
        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Call a function that loads the tips.
            LoadTips();
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In the page's OnAppearing() method, I have the label's text set to the current tip (which at this point is null) and I subscribe the function that updates it to the event that the timer fires.

```
using Partylist.Models;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Partylist.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class EventsPage : ContentPage
    {
        // Text of the tip banner.
        public string BannerText { get; set; }

        // List of events, used to populate 
        // the page's ListView (see the XAML).
        public ObservableCollection<Event> EventList { get; set; }

        // Constructor.
        public EventsPage()
        {
            // Does all the stuff to make the page
            // exist that doesn't involve anything 
            // specific to this particular page in
            // this particular app.
            InitializeComponent();
            // Set the label's BindingContext to the 
            // App class so it can update its text.
            tipLabel.BindingContext = (App)App.Current;
        }

        // Runs when the page appears.
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            // Call the regular OnAppearing method.
            base.OnAppearing();

            // Set the BindingContext of the page to itself.
            BindingContext = this;

            // Update the ListView.
            UpdateListView();

            // Set the banner's text to the current tip's sumamry.
            tipLabel.Text = ((App)App.Current).CurrentTip.Summary;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentTip");

            // Subscribe the OnTipUpdate function to the tipUpdate event in the app
            // class.
            App.TipUpdate += OnTipUpdate;
        }

        // Function to update the ListView whent he page loads or when something changes.
        private void UpdateListView()
        {
            // Set the EventList to a new ObservableCollection
            // which will be populated.
            EventList = new ObservableCollection<Event>();

            // Loop to populate the ObservableCollection.
            for (int i = 0; i < Directory.GetDirectories(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    Environment.SpecialFolder
                    .LocalApplicationData))
                .Length; i++)
            {
                // Add a new event.
                EventList.Add(new Event()
                {
                    // Set the folder name to the name of the folder 
                    // that the even corresponds to.
                    FolderName = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetDirectories(
                    Environment.GetFolderPath(
                        Environment.SpecialFolder
                        .LocalApplicationData))[i]).Name,
                    // Sets the date/time created to the folder's
                    // creation date.
                    DateCreated = Directory
                    .GetCreationTime(Directory.GetDirectories(
                    Environment.GetFolderPath(
                        Environment.SpecialFolder
                        .LocalApplicationData))[i]),
                    // Sets the date/time last edited to the 
                    // folder's write date.
                    DateEdited = Directory
                    .GetLastWriteTime(Directory.GetDirectories(
                    Environment.GetFolderPath(
                        Environment.SpecialFolder
                        .LocalApplicationData))[i])
                });
                // Set the ItemsSource of the ListView in the 
                // XAML to the ObservableCollection.
                EventsListView.ItemsSource = EventList;
                // Calls OnPropertyChanged() which makes the ListView update.
                OnPropertyChanged("EventList");
            }
        }

        // Function to go to the "New Event" page.
        async void OnNewEventClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new NewEventPage());
        }

        // Function for when a ListView item is selected.
        async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            App.selectedEvent = (Event)e.SelectedItem;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ListsPage());
        }

        // Function to delete an event if the "Delete" context action is selected.
        async void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Represents the thing to be deleted.
            var del = (MenuItem)sender;
            // Displays a confirmnation popup and stores the user's answer in a variable.
            var answer = await DisplayAlert("Delete this event?", 
                "Are you sure you want to delete the event: \"" + 
                ((Event)del.CommandParameter).FolderName + "\"?", "Delete", "Cancel");
            // If the user accepted, delete the event with the MenuItem that ran this function.
            if (answer)
            {
                Directory.Delete(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), 
                    ((Event)del.CommandParameter).FolderName), true);
                // Set the ItemsSource to null and back to make the ListView update.
                EventsListView.ItemsSource = null;
                UpdateListView();
            }
        }

        // Function for when the current tip updates.
        public void OnTipUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Make the label's text update.
            tipLabel.Text = ((App)App.Current).CurrentTip.Summary;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentTip");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here is the page's XAML in case something is wrong with that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Partylist.Views.EventsPage"
             Title="Events"
             BackgroundColor="White">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="settings_gear.png"
                     Priority="0"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <!--Main layout of the page-->
        <StackLayout>
            <!--ListView of the events-->
            <ListView x:Name="EventsListView"
                      ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <!--These contewxt actions are buttons that appear
                            when you long press the item (Android) or swipe 
                            left (iOS).-->
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Clicked="OnDelete"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                          Text="Delete"
                                          IsDestructive="true"/>
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <!--This is the content that actually appears-->
                            <StackLayout Padding="20,5">
                                <Label Text="{Binding FolderName}"
                                       TextColor="#FF7700"
                                       FontSize="Large"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

            <!--"New Event" button-->
            <Button Text="+ Add New Event"
                    TextColor="#ff418b"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    BackgroundColor="#00ffffff"
                    Clicked="OnNewEventClicked"/>

            <!--The banner at the bottom of the screen that gives tips-->
            <Frame BorderColor="#ff418b"
                   Padding="0">
                <FlexLayout Direction="Row"
                            AlignItems="Stretch"
                            JustifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                    <!--The "Tip" icon-->
                    <Image Source="tip_icon.png"
                           Margin="10"
                           FlexLayout.Basis="50"/>
                    <!--The short version of the tip-->
                    <Label x:Name="tipLabel"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="#bb0099"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FlexLayout.Basis="250"/>
                    <!--The button that opens up a screen 
                    with tyhe rest of the tip-->
                    <Button Text="More"
                            TextColor="White"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            BackgroundColor="#ff418b"
                            FlexLayout.Basis="100"/>
                </FlexLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I keep my app from breaking when the label updates?

Comment: there is not enough code here to tell why the "entire app" breaks, but I would suggest you use data binding to update the label rather than an event

Comment: Can you please provide us a [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? And there is no need to  set the text of label to null.

Comment: @Jason I already had the binding context set to the page's code-behind and I didn't want to change it to the App class and back.

Comment: the Label can have it's own BindingContext

Comment: @Jason How do I do that? Because apparently, adding BindingContext="Partylist.App" and Text="{Binding CurrentTip.summary}" doesn't work (Partylist is the name of the app, App is the App class, and CurrentTip is the tip with the text that I want to display except I changed the tip from a field into a property).

Comment: `myLabel.BindingContext = myModel;`

Comment: @Jason Setting the binding context to the App class gave me a red underline, so I set it to the "CurrentTip" property in that class and it still says the "Summary" property in CurrentTip was not found. (I did make sure it was a property and not a field.)

Comment: what is the **actual error** causing the "red underline" when you use `App` as the `BindingContext`?  It's difficult for me to give you exact code without knowing more about your model.  But I'll note that in your post, you use "summary" and "currentTip", not "Summary" and "CurrentTip"

Comment: @Jason The error for the red underline says, "App is a type, which is not valid in the given context", and I changed the capitalization for "Summary" and "CurrentTip" because I changed them from fields to properties so the binding would see them  (it didn't work).

Comment: try `App.Current` to refer to the current instance

Comment: @Jason I tried that and Visual Studio said I could simplify it and when I told it to, it changed it to "Application.Current". Then, I changed the label's text property in XAML to be "{Binding CurrentTip.Summary}" and I got this in the output console: "[0:] Binding: 'CurrentTip' property not found on 'Partylist.App', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'"

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I changed the post so it includes the entire App class and all of the page's XAML and code-behind, in case it was helpful. Anything else that might be related is probably under-the-hood stuff that I don't know where it is.

Comment: try casting it `myLabel.BindingContext = (App)App.Current;`

Comment: @Jason It still wants me to simplify from App.Current to Application.Current. It's not an error, though, just a suggestion. It also still doesn't see the CurrentTip property. I checked to make sure the property was public, and it is, but it is also static. Does that matter?

Comment: @Jason Nevermind. I made it not be static and now I'm not getting the message in the console saying that the property wasn't found, but the label isn't updating.

Comment: you need to use INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I implemented it in the App class and called the OnPropertyChanged() function in the page's OnAppearing() method. I also made the function on the page that was supposed to update the label before I asked this question call the OnPropertyChanged() function. Everything works at the moment except that the label only updates after the page has been reloaded, not when the App class's timer goes off.

Comment: Can you please show us your updated code of class App?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I just rewrote the post. Sorry it took so long.

Comment: Can you please try to add a breakpoint at OnTipUpdate method to check if the codes has been hit to update the label?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT It's definitely hitting the code, but right after it updates the first time is when it breaks. After that point, it apparently does keep hitting the break point when it should, but the banner's text doesn't actually change - probably because the app is broken by this point. I actually had a thought recently that maybe its running on the wrong thread because I don't know how to do multi-threaded programming and that is what these Xamarin apps try to use. Could that be the problem?

Comment: You can try to update the text in main thread by [Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT That fixed it completely. Thank you so much.

Comment: I just added an answer and can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the text in `Main thread`:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
  label.Text = "Async operation completed";
});
```

Refer: [xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms)